# How to disable text input based on selected radio button?

Tags: javascript

I have two radio buttons, and depending on the selected state, I want certain `<input>` textual fields to be disabled.

Here's a basic example of this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Holy Grail Mockup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="first">
      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="second">
      <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
    </form>
  </body>
  <script>
    if (document.getElementById('first').checked) {
      document.getElementById('text').disabled = true;
    } else if (document.getElementById('second').checked) {
      document.getElementById('text').disabled = false;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use an event listener to listen for changes in the radio button value

Comment: This would ensure that the user can never enable the text input if they click a radio by accident, or even if they change their mind.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to make an **eventListener**, but if you are insisting with your current code, I'll leave this scratch so you can start on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Holy Grail Mockup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      Disable:<input onclick="enableDisable()" type="radio" name="radios" id="first">
      Enable:<input onclick="enableDisable()" type="radio" name="radios" id="second">
      <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
    </form>
  </body>
  <script>
  function enableDisable(){
    document.getElementById('first').checked ?  
 document.getElementById('text').disabled = true
   : document.getElementById('text').disabled = false
  }
  </script>
</html>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/neyubee/pen/qBQByXB)

Comment: Your code doesn't work, check always before post.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you execute the code incorrectly. I edit the code.

Comment: You had a extra `;` in your code ;)

Comment: Thank's for the correction.